# How to count the number of commas within a string column (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have an Excel file that includes a column originally stores dictionary-type data look like below:

I imported it into PD frame and I plan to count the number of elements for each row and save the result as another output which represents the number of elements.

Since there's no clear pattern for the elements where some elements are quoted and others are not, my strategy is to just count the number of commas.

I've been searching for a good code to address this for a few hours..Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
Have

index dic
0     {a,"b",c,d,"d"}
1     {"e","f",g,h,"j",l}
...
```

```
Want

index dic                  num_element
0     {a,"b",c,d,"d"}      5
1     {"e","f",g,h,"j",l}  6
...
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df.to_dict()` for an unambiguous input? (Or provide the input as DataFrame constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have **strings**, you could use:

```
df['num_element'] = df['dic'].str.count(',').add(1)
```

Output:

```
   index                  dic  num_element
0      0      {a,"b",c,d,"d"}            5
1      1  {"e","f",g,h,"j",l}            6
```